# Regex conditionals in Python

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a number if certain conditions are met:
if word1 is followed by word2 before the number, I'd like to match the first number that comes before word1; if word1 is followed by the number before word2, then I'd like the first occurance of the number that is followed by word1.

I have tried it using two opposite lookarounds: (?=regex)then|(?!regex)else but it did not work. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
(?=(word1[\s\S]+?word2[\s\S]+?[\d\.]{1,},\d{2}\s+EUR))((?<=word4)[\s\S]+?([\d\.]{1,},\d{2})\s+EUR[\s\S]+?(?=word1))|(?!word1[\s\S]+?[\d\.]{1,},\d{2}\s+EUR[\s\S]+?word2)word1[\s\S]+?([\d\.]{1,},\d{2})\s+EUR
```

Here are some concrete examples:

case1

\n28.000,00 EUR\nword3\n308,24 EUR\nword4\nword5\nword1\n2.096,64 EUR\nword2\n308,24 EUR
expected match: 2.096,64

case2

\n28.000,00 EUR\nword3\n308,24 EUR\nword4\n2.096,64 EUR\nword5\nword1\nword2\n308,24 EUR
expected match: 2.096,64

I have used word4 in my regex as an anchor in order to match the first number before word1. word4 is not a requirement and can be disregarded.

https://regex101.com/r/F8uQZU/2

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a few concrete examples of text and the corresponding expected output? (So not only behind a link)

Comment: Your regex makes reference to "word4", which you didn't mention in your requirements. Can you clarify?

Comment: So we can ignore "word4" as a requirement? I mean, if there is no occurrence of word4, would the expected result be any different? Can you also add the expected output for the two example cases?

Comment: What should happen with `1 EUR word1 blabla word2 5 EUR word2`? (notice `word2` appears twice, and so we get a combination of the two patterns).

Comment: Perhaps you can use 2 capture groups, and exclude any of the data formats in between the matches `\b(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})(?:(?!\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}).)*word1\\nword2|word1(?:(?!\\nword2).)*?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2})` See https://regex101.com/r/vfOKMB/1 Or with newlines https://regex101.com/r/XBarSm/1

Comment: Thanks that comes really close to what I am looking for but for some reason it doesn't match the 2 in front of the dot in case2 https://regex101.com/r/vfOKMB/1. It only matches 096,64 instead of 2.096,64

Comment: @P.Reinhart Ah I see, I added a word boundary `\b` at the beginning of the pattern. You can omit it. https://regex101.com/r/xZjOoD/1 You are working with the `\n` literally right? As in a backslash followed by an `n` char?

Comment: wow you're amazing. thank you so much :)

Comment: Any reaction to my last question, @P.Reinhart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use 2 capture groups to get the values, with an alternation `|` for both of the cases:

```
(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}) EUR(?:(?!\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}).)*word1\\nword2|word1(?:(?!\\nword2).)*?(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}) EUR
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
  - `(?:\.\d{3})*` Optionally repeat matching `.` and 3 digits
  - `,\d{2}` Match `,` and 2 digits
- `) EUR` Close capture group `, and match`  EUR` after it
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?!\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}).` Negative lookahead, assert not the number format to the right, and if so, match any char except a newline using the dot
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all characters
- `word1\\nword2` Match `word1\nword2`
- `|` Or
- `word1` Match literally
- `(?:(?!\\nword2).)*?` Negative lookahead, assert not `\nword2` to the right, and if so, match any char except a newline using the dot. Repeat the outer non capture group again as least as possible, making the quantifier non greedy
- `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*,\d{2}) EUR` Capture the number format in **group 2** and match the following  `EUR`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qMWDS0/1)